# Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4 xml autocomplete not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

Today I updated my Android Studio to the newest stable version  `Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4`
and whenever open xml most of command not showing in prediction in even if old or new projects and some of attributes is Unknown in xml
like margin / scale type .. etc
i've tried many of solutions that not working like
1- invalidate caches  / restart
2- remove .idea folder
3- reinstall android studio and sdk
[image]

Thank you in advance. A portion of error is listed below

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure:**

1. You disabled `Power Save Mode` under `File`
2. You enable auto completion mode in `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Code Completion` -> `Show suggestions as you type` (Tick box)

My settings to use for a good coding experience:

[image: Code Completion Settings]

Comment: Same problem. in my case suggestions is working but not showing all attributes

Comment: By what View is your ImageView surrounding? RelativeLayout or LinearLayout? I can investigate a bit further.

Comment: LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout or any root layout facing same problem